# Lack of gradient when creating tensor from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, autograd

Can someone please explain to me the following behavior?

```
import torch
import numpy as np

z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.]), requires_grad=True).float()

def pre_main(z):
  return z * 3.0
  
  
x = pre_main(z)
x.backward(torch.tensor([1., 1.]))
print(z.grad)
```

prints:

```
None
```

Meanwhile:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

z = torch.tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad=True).float()

def pre_main(z):
  return z * 3.0
  
  
x = pre_main(z)
x.backward(torch.tensor([1., 1.]))
print(z.grad)
```

prints:

```
tensor([3., 3.])
```

Why are my gradients being destroyed when constructing from a numpy array?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gradient is not destroyed: `grad` returns `None` because it has never been saved on the `grad` attribute. This is because non-leaf tensors don't have their gradients stored during backpropagation. Hence the warning message you received when running your first snippet:

> UserWarning: The `.grad` attribute of a `Tensor` that is not a leaf `Tensor` is being accessed. Its `.grad` attribute won't be populated during `autograd.backward()`.

This is the case for your `z` tensor when it is defined as:

```
>>> z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.]), requires_grad=True).float()
>>> z.is_leaf
False
```

Compared to:

```
>>> z = torch.tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad=True).float()
>>> z.is_leaf
True
```

which means the latter will have its gradient value in `z.grad`.

But notice that:

```
>>> z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.]), requires_grad=True)
>>> z.is_leaf
True
```

To further explain this: when a tensor is first initialized it is a leaf node (`.is_leaf` returns `True`). As soon as you apply a function on it (here `.float()` is an *in-place* operator) it is not a leaf anymore since it has parents in the computational graph.

So really, there's nothing to *fix*... What you can do though is make sure the gradient is saved on `z.grad` when the backward pass is called. So, the second question comes down to **how to store/access the gradient on a non-leaf node?**.

---

Now, if you would like to store the gradient on `.backward()` call. You could use [`retain_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.retain_grad) as explained in the warning message:

```
z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.]), requires_grad=True).float()
z.retain_grad()
```

Or, since we expected it to be a leaf node, solve it by using `FloatTensor` to convert the `numpy.array` to a `torch.Tensor`:

```
z = torch.FloatTensor(np.array([1., 1.]))
z.requires_grad=True
```

Alternatively, you could stick with `torch.tensor` and supply a `dtype`:

```
z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.]), dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the numpy array to a tensor, and then specify that you need the gradient:

```
z = torch.from_numpy(np.array([1., 1.])).float() 
z = torch.tensor(z, requires_grad=True)
  
x = pre_main(z)
x.backward(torch.tensor([1., 1.]))
print(z.grad)
```

A little more digging is showing me that if you remove the float conversion `.float()` after creating your initial tensor the gradient calculation works. You can accomplish this by specifying the dtype in the numpy array itself if feasible:

```
z = torch.tensor(np.array([1., 1.], dtype=np.float32), requires_grad=True)
x = pre_main(z)
x.backward(torch.tensor([1., 1.]))
print(z.grad)
```